# Excahnge Server: Modify attachment (change codec of audio file) before delivery

Tags: exchange-server, codec, voicemail

We have a situation where our phone system will deliver voice-mail as email attachments to the phone. The problem is the format (while wav) uses a proprietary codec that most mobile device users cannot playback. I need for our Exchange server (Exchange 2003) to parse the incoming file, convert it to a usable format and then deliver the attachment.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you spoken to the phone system vendor about encoding the messages in a reasonable format?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. They are not able to provide a better format.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?   I would really like to solve the same problem.